# Problem in populating a subform in zend framework

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, zend-form

I am building an abstracted form in Zend framework. This is done by creating dynamic form elements from the database (Tables with key / value values).
Most of it is working just fine except for the setDefault/populate function of the form. Let me explain.

I have a main form with 3 subforms attached to it (wizard style form).  The 3th step of the form has 5 or more dynamic elements. (for example: properties of a server rack).
The form in step 3 can be cloned using ajax. (So you would be able to add 4 server racks at once).  When submitting the form a preValidation() function will check all fields that are new and add them to the subform.
So fine so good.  Now the problems start.

When adding fields to the subform I use the factory way of creating form elements =>

```
$subForm->addElement($presentation_type,'fixedField'. $key.'_'.$formStep, 
array('label' => $label.':',
'required'     => $is_mandatory,
'filter'       => $filters,
'value'        => $value,
'description'  => $unit .' '. $description,
'validators'   => $validators));
```

This works fine when starting a new unsubmitted form, but fails to set the value parameter when the form is submitted, he does not populate the value parameter (the other parameters within the same function work just fine).
I upgraded zend framework to the latest version, Tried finding my problem on google and forums, but no success.

I'll send you a Belgium beer if you solve it :)
Been looking for 3 days now.

Also tried using the setDefault function and the populate function.

Weird thing is when i do "echo $subForm->getElement('xxxxxx')->getValue();" i get the correct output.  So it seems that zend just won't render the value inside the element.

Controller code:

```
<?php
class TestController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    protected $_form;
    protected $_namespace = 'TestController';
    protected $_session;

    /**
     * Gets the add/edit form for the current object
     *
     * @access public
     * @return object|void
     * @param boolean $search_form Set to true if you want the search form object to be returned
     */
    public function getForm()
    {
        if (null === $this->_form) {
            $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
            $this->_form = new Application_Form_Test();

        }
        return $this->_form;
    }

    /**
     * Action for the new page
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function newAction (){


        //Store the parent object in a session, this way we can use the var in the 3th form step
        $this->getSessionNamespace();

        // Either re-display the current page, or grab the "next"
        // (first) sub form
        if (!$form = $this->getCurrentSubForm()) {
            $form = $this->getNextSubForm();
        }

        $this->view->form = $this->getForm()->prepareSubForm($form);

    }

     /**
     * Action to process the multi step form
     *
     * @access public
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function processAction(){

        //No form is set
        if (!$form = $this->getCurrentSubForm()) {
            return $this->_forward('new');
        }

        if (!$this->subFormIsValid($form, $this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
            $this->view->form = $this->getForm()->prepareSubForm($form);
            return $this->render('new');
        }

        if (!$this->formIsValid()) {
            $form = $this->getNextSubForm();
            $this->view->form = $this->getForm()->prepareSubForm($form);
            return $this->render('new');
        }

        // Valid form!
        // Let's save everything
        //......

        // All done, clear the sessions
        Zend_Session::namespaceUnset($this->_namespace);
        //$this->render('index');
        $this->_forward('index');
    }

    /**
     * Ajax action that returns the dynamic form field for step3 in the form
     */
    public function newajaxformAction() {

      if(!$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) throw new Zend_Controller_Action_Exception("This isn't a Ajax request !", 404);

      $ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
      $ajaxContext->addActionContext('newfield', 'html')->initContext();

      //Disable view
      $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
      $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();

      $id = $this->_getParam('id', null);
      $amount = $this->_getParam('amount', null);

      $fieldsKeys = $_POST['key'];
      $fieldsValues = $_POST['value'];

      //This one adds multiple objects on one page
      $po = new Test_Partial($id,$amount,$fieldsKeys,$fieldsValues);

      echo $po->__toString();
    }

    /**
     * Get the session namespace we're using
     *
     * @access public
     * @return Zend_Session_Namespace
     */
    public function getSessionNamespace()
    {
        if (null === $this->_session) {
            $this->_session = new Zend_Session_Namespace($this->_namespace);
        }

        return $this->_session;
    }

    /**
     * Get a list of forms already stored in the session
     *
     * @access public
     * @return array
     */
    public function getStoredForms()
    {
        $stored = array();
        foreach ($this->getSessionNamespace() as $key => $value) {
            $stored[] = $key;
        }

        return $stored;
    }

    /**
     * Get list of all subforms available
     *
     * @access public
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPotentialForms()
    {
        return array_keys($this->getForm()->getSubForms());
    }

    /**
     * What sub form was submitted?
     *
     * @access public
     * @return false|Zend_Form_SubForm
     */
    public function getCurrentSubForm()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if (!$request->isPost()) {
            return false;
        }

        foreach ($this->getPotentialForms() as $name) {
            if ($data = $request->getPost($name, false)) {
                if (is_array($data)) {
                    return $this->getForm()->getSubForm($name);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the next sub form to display
     *
     * @return Zend_Form_SubForm|false
     * @access public
     */
    public function getNextSubForm()
    {
        $storedForms    = $this->getStoredForms();
        $potentialForms = $this->getPotentialForms();

        foreach ($potentialForms as $name) {
            if (!in_array($name, $storedForms)) {
                return $this->getForm()->getSubForm($name);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Is the sub form valid?
     *
     * @param  Zend_Form_SubForm $subForm
     * @param  array $data
     * @return bool
     */
    public function subFormIsValid(Zend_Form_SubForm $subForm,array $data)
    {
        $name = $subForm->getName();

        echo '<br />Submitted data(Send from Controller) = <pre>';
            print_r($data);
        echo '</pre>';

        if ($subForm->isValid($data)) {
            $this->getSessionNamespace()->$name = $subForm->getValues();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Is the full form valid?
     *
     * @return bool
     * @access public
     */
    public function formIsValid()
    {
        $data = array();
        foreach ($this->getSessionNamespace() as $key => $info) {
            $data[$key] = $info[$key];
        }

        return (count($this->getStoredForms()) < count($this->getPotentialForms()))? false : $this->getForm()->isValid($data);
    }
}
?>


Form Code:

<?php
class Application_Form_Test extends Zend_Form {

    public function init() {

        //Set some filters for are fields
        $this->setElementFilters(array('StringTrim'));

        //Lets make some subforms = > each subform will be on a different page
        //Step 1
        $step1 = new Zend_Form_SubForm();

        $step1->addElement('select', 'test', array(     'label' => 'Save in:',
                                                    'multiOptions' => array('choose'=>'Choose one ...','a'=>'a','b'=>'b'),
                                                    'required'     => false,
                                                    'ignore' => true,
                                                    'value'        => array('choose'),
                                                    'validators'   => array(array('InArray',false,array(array_keys(array('choose'=>'Choose one ...','a'=>'a','b'=>'b')))))));



        // Step 3
        $step2 = new Zend_Form_SubForm();

        // Add a remove and add button for the dynamic forms
        $step2->addElement('text', 'addFormAmount', array('label' => '',
                                                        'required' => false,
                                                        'ignore'=> true,
                                                        'value'        => 1,
                                                        'description'  => 'objects.',
                                                        'order' => 99992
        ));

        $step2->addElement('button', 'addForm', array('label' => 'Add',
                                                        'order' => 99991
        ));

        $step2->getElement('addForm')->setAttrib('onClick', 'ajaxAddForm();');

        // Add a hidden id field, this way we can use the id in javascript to count the numner of fields
        $step2->addElement('hidden', 'id', array('value' => 1));

            $this->addAbstractField($step2,'',1,'test value');


        //test, let's put our prevalidation at the end of the form object
        $this->preValidation($step2,$_POST);

        // Finally attach sub forms to main form
        $this->addSubForms(array(
            'step1' => $step1,
            'step2' => $step2
        ));
    }


    /**
     * Create a sluggable string for forms or any other uri related string
     *
     * @return mixed
     * @access public
     * @param mixed $array
     */
    protected function getSlug($string){
         $slug = trim($string); // trim the string
         $slug= preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/','',$slug ); // only take alphanumerical characters, but keep the spaces and dashes too…
         $slug= str_replace(' ','-', $slug); // replace spaces by dashes
         $slug= strtolower($slug); // make it lowercase
         return $slug;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare a sub form for display
     *
     * @param  string|Zend_Form_SubForm $spec
     * @return Zend_Form_SubForm
     */
    public function prepareSubForm($spec)
    {
        if (is_string($spec)) {
            $subForm = $this->{$spec};
        } elseif ($spec instanceof Zend_Form_SubForm) {
            $subForm = $spec;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Invalid argument passed to ' . __FUNCTION__ . '()');
        }
        $this->setSubFormDefaultDecorators($subForm)
             ->addSubmitButton($subForm)
             ->addSubFormActions($subForm);

        return $subForm;
    }

    /**
     * Add form decorators to an individual sub form
     *
     * @param  Zend_Form_SubForm $subForm
     * @return My_Form_Registration
     */
    public function setSubFormDefaultDecorators(Zend_Form_SubForm $subForm)
    {
        $subForm->setDecorators(array(
            'FormElements',
            array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dl','class' => 'zend_form')),'Form',));
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add a submit button to an individual sub form
     *
     * @param  Zend_Form_SubForm $subForm
     * @return My_Form_Registration
     */
    public function addSubmitButton(Zend_Form_SubForm $subForm)
    {
        $subForm->addElement(new Zend_Form_Element_Submit(
            'save',
            array(
                'label'    => 'Save and continue',
                'required' => false,
                'ignore'   => true,
                'order' => 99999
            )));

        $subForm->getElement('save')->setAttrib('onClick', 'ajaxController(); $("#processing_alert").css("display", "block");');

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add action and method to sub form
     *
     * @param  Zend_Form_SubForm $subForm
     * @return My_Form_Registration
     */
    public function addSubFormActions(Zend_Form_SubForm $subForm)
    {
        $subForm->setAction('/test/process')
                ->setMethod('post')
                ->setEnctype(Zend_Form::ENCTYPE_MULTIPART);
        return $this;
    }

/**
 * After post, pre validation hook
 *
 * Finds all fields where name includes 'newField' and uses addNewField to add
 * them to the form object
 *
 * @param array $data $_GET or $_POST
 */
public function preValidation(Zend_Form_SubForm $subForm,array $data) {
  // array_filter callback
  function findFields($field) {
    // return field names that include 'newField'
    if (strpos($field, 'newField') !== false) {
      return $field;
    }
  }

  // Search $data for dynamically added fields using findFields callback
  $newFields = array_filter(array_keys($data), 'findFields');

  foreach ($newFields as $fieldName) {
    // strip the id number off of the field name and use it to set new order
    $ex1 = explode('newField', $fieldName);
    $ex2 = explode('_',$ex1[1]);
    $key = $ex2[0];
    $order = $ex2[1];

    $this->addAbstractField($subForm,$key, $order,$data[$fieldName]);
    //echo 'order :'.$order." and key is " .$key."<br />"; test ok
  }
}

/**
 * Adds new fields to form dynamically
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $value
 * @param int    $order
 * @param object $subForm
 *
 */
public function addAbstractField(Zend_Form_SubForm $subForm,  $key, $formStep=null,$value){

                $subForm->addElement('text','fixedField'. $key.'_'.$formStep, array('label' => 'Test label:',
                                                                                            'required'     => 'true',
                                                                                            'value'        => $value,
                                                                                            'description'  => 'test description'));

            echo '<br />Added element to subform (Send from Form method) key = "fixedField'. $key.'_'.$formStep .'" and value "'.$value.'"<br />';
            return $this;
    }
}
?>


Form Partial code:

<?php
class Test_Partial {

    protected $id;
    public function __construct($id,$amount=1,$fieldsKeys=array(),$fieldsValues=array())
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->amount = is_int( (int)$amount) ? $amount: 1 ;
        $this->fields = array();

        //Lets combine both arrays into one
        foreach ($fieldsKeys as $key => $value){
            $ex = explode('fixedField',$value);
            $ex2 = explode('_',$ex[1]);
            $this->fields[$ex2[0]] = $fieldsValues[$key];
        }
    }

    public function get() {
        $result_array = array();
        $amount_counter = 1;

        while ($amount_counter <= $this->amount) {

            $result_array[] = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('newField'. $keyvalue['id'].'_'.($this->id+$amount_counter), array(    'label' => 'test:',
                                                                                                                'required'     => true,
                                                                                                                'value'      => 'this data will be lost'));


        $tikk = new Zend_Form_Element_Button('removeForm'.($this->id+$amount_counter), array('label' => 'Remove'));
            $tikk->setAttrib('onClick', 'ajaxRemoveForm('.($this->id+$amount_counter).')');

            $result_array[] = $tikk;
            ++ $amount_counter;
        }

        return $result_array;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return implode('', $this->get());
    }

    /**
     * Create a sluggable string for forms or any other uri related string
     *
     * @return mixed
     * @access public
     * @param mixed $array
     */
    protected function getSlug($string){
         $slug = trim($string); // trim the string
         $slug= preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/','',$slug ); // only take alphanumerical characters, but keep the spaces and dashes too…
         $slug= str_replace(' ','-', $slug); // replace spaces by dashes
         $slug= strtolower($slug); // make it lowercase
         return $slug;
    }
}
?>

View:

<script type="text/javascript">
function getLastSubId(){
    var maxc = 0;
    // Remove all elements with a certain sub id
    $('*').each(function() {
        num = parseInt(this.id.split("_")[1],10);
        if(num > maxc)
        {
           maxc = num;

        }
    });
    return maxc;
}

// Retrieve new element's html from action controller
function ajaxAddForm(amount) {
    // Diplay processing msg
    $("#processing_alert").css("display", "block");

    // Get value of id - integer appended to dynamic form field names and ids
    var id = $("#step2-id").val();

    if(typeof amount == 'undefined'){
        var amount = $("#step2-addFormAmount").val();
    }

    var fields = '';

    // Collect all field keys and values and include them in the ajax request.
    $('*[id*=step2-fixedField]:visible').each(function() {
          var key = $(this).attr('id');
          var value = $(this).attr('value');
          fields  += '&key[]='+key+'&value[]='+value;
    });

    $.ajax(
    {
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo $this->url(array('action' => 'newAjaxForm')); ?>",
      data: "id=" + id + "&amount=" + amount + fields,
      async: false,
      success: function(newForm) {

        // Insert new element before the Add button
        var counter = parseInt(id) + parseInt(amount);

        $("#addForm-label").before(newForm);
        $("#step2-id").val(counter);
      }
    }
  );
    // Disable processing msg
    $("#processing_alert").css("display", "none");
}

function ajaxRemoveForm(id) {
    // Diplay processing msg
    $("#processing_alert").css("display", "block");

    // Remove the "remove" button that we just pressed + label
    $("#removeForm"+id+"-label").remove();
    $("#removeForm"+id+"-element").remove();

    // Remove all elements with a certain sub id
    $('*[id*=_'+id+'-]:visible').each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });

    // Disable processing msg
    $("#processing_alert").css("display", "none");
}
</script>
<?php echo $this->form; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same problematic in Mauritius :)

I guess you base your ajax generated extra fields on Jeremy Kendall's tutorial:

http://www.jeremykendall.net/2009/01/19/dynamically-adding-elements-to-zend-form/

It took me a long time to get this to work.

I've modified his tutorial this way:

In my main form definition, I got the function preValidation and addNewExperience (I work on a CV online).

```
public function preValidation(array $data) {

        // array_filter callback
        function findSubForms($subForms) {
            // return field names that include 'newName'
            if (strpos($subForms, 'experience') !== false) {
                return $subForms;
            }
        }

        // Search $data for dynamically added fields using findFields callback
        $newSubForms = array_filter(array_keys($data), 'findSubForms');

        foreach ($newSubForms as $subForm) {
            // strip the id number off of the field name and use it to set new order

            $order = ltrim($subForm, 'experience') + 3;
            $this->addNewExperience($subForm, $data[$subForm], $order);

        }
    }



public function addNewExperience($name, $value, $order) {

        $mysubForm = new Application_Form_Experience();
        $this->addSubForm($mysubForm, $name, $order);
    }
```

So,

either the form pass validation in which case it will go to model and insert in DB, or the validation fails and the form has to be displayed with typed in values.

In which case, preValidation is launched, the newly added subForms are re-displayed with the newly added values.

It totally works for me. And I think I don't even need $value in addNewExperience (it's not used in the function). Zend is just good at finding where values belong too when your array is populated.

I'm struggling with formatting the form into a table :/ The structure is a bit fragile. If I touch the decorators slightly the form stops populating properly.

Not quite sure what's going on and as you've find out, there's not many of us doing this kind of stuff online.